# 'User' doesn't contain a definition in my Public Action Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

been making a database to store users details when they register and have a login/logout page. All was going dandy until when the database updates in the 'UserController' and I get this error:

```
> 'Mvcflight.RegistrationEntities' does not contain a definition for
> 'User' and no extension method 'User' accepting a first argument of
> type 'Mvcflight.RegistrationEntities' could be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Of course nothing happens on the actual website and nothing saves to the database.

```
    public ActionResult Register(User U)
        {
            using (RegistrationEntities dc = new RegistrationEntities())
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {           

                    //you should check duplicate registration here 
                    dc.User.Add(U);
                    dc.SaveChanges();
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    U = null;
                    ViewBag.Message = "Successfully Registration Done";

            }
            return View(U);
        }
```

The database can't update I don't know why, any ideas?
    Here's my class:

```
    public  class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide username", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string userName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be 8 char long.")]
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password dose not match.")]
        [DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Password)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide full name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        public string fullName { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([\+\-_\.][0-9a-zA-Z]+)*)+@(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,3})$",
            ErrorMessage = "Please provide valid email id")]
        public string userEmail { get; set; }
    }
```

And my HTML code:

```
    <h2>Register</h2>
@model Mvcflight.Models.User
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border:solid 1px green">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userEmail)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userEmail)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fullName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fullName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fullName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

To note I have another database on the website, both sharing my 'FlightClass'

Thanks for any and all help, let me know if you need more info/code!!

:)

Comment: Pluralize the `User`. Try `Users` probably works. Also make sure that your connection string is pointing to the correct database.

Comment: Hi, 'Users' doesn't work, already tried it. My connection string is pointing to 'LocalDB' so is the other connection string. But it is pointing to the right DB.